# Sync Local Persistent Storage in Kubernetes Pods with NFS Share

Tags: kubernetes, synchronization, nfs

I'm trying to run kubernetes pods that need persistent storage with that storage local.  I need a solution that syncs (2 ways) between the volume in the pod and an NFS share.

I've seen a few ideas (Unison), but no concrete ways to do it.  No, I don't mind waiting for the sync to complete each time a new pod spins up.  Also, every pod has only 1x replica, so this isn't super complicated.

Comment: Multiple concurrent 2-way sync of arbitrary file content _is_ a hard problem.  You don't seem to be asking a question about programming but rather looking for a tool; see the [help/on-topic] for some details about what's allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You’re right.  So sorry about that.